# Order of properties matter with jQuery animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

After just now spending too much time debugging why my jQuery `animate()` calls stopped working correctly, I realized my problem was the properties in the `animate()` call have to be in a specific order.  So the following will **not** work properly:

```
$('div.example').animate({left: 50, top: 100, opacity: 1});
```

What will happen is the `div.example` will fade in (if it wasn't already) and will *just appear* at position left:50, top:100, it will not animate.  To get this to work as expected, you have to reorder:

```
$('div.example').animate({opacity: 1, left: 50, top: 100});
```

I tested this in FF4 and Chrome.  This surprised me as I wasn't even aware that Javascript guaranteed order of properties in objects and jQuery makes no mention of this requirement in their docs.  So my question is basically, am I doing something wrong?  Is this expected?  Is there documentation on what the proper order is?  Will this work properly in all browsers?

I'm using jQuery UI as well.  I know that enhances the standard animate method to allow for animating colors and such.  Is that potentially the issue?

Comment: Thats silly, json objects don't matter what order they are of, unless its a css problem, because jquery would read them in a for loop, or by directly accessing the option.left, and so on. order should not matter here,

Comment: this is a really strange behavior. As you mentioned, there is no order guarantee and the problem does not scale with the fact whether or not `opacity` is set. Has my attention..

Comment: That is very strange indeed. Confirmed I receive the same behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/Tpb5z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a jQuery bug: [cannot animate position and opacity at same time](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9074) but is fixed in 1.6.**1**

In the meantime, you can fix it by adding "px" on the end:

```
$('div.example').animate({top: '100px', left: '50px', opacity: 1});
```

Comment: I am using the latest (automatically through google's CDN).  Hmm, looks like the latest according to google is v1.6.0.  I guess 1.6.1 must've just come out.  Well at least the temporary fix of having a specific order works.  Thanks for the explanation and alternate workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Does your properties `left` and `top` are declared earlier in css? Some browsers (webkit if I remember correctly) have problems animating properties that weren't declared. Try setting `left` and `top` to 0 or some other values and see if it works.